# picking random in python

Tags: python, random

I am new to python, so I apologise if the answer is obvious.

I am trying to pick 10 random numbers from a range of 128 numbers. And then if a certain number is present in this list, then print the (list) or a (word) or something.

I can pick the 10 random numbers and print these random numbers, but I am having trouble printing if a number is present in this random list.

I am picking and printing the 10 random numbers in the following way:

```
import random
list = random.sample(range(128), 10)
print list
```

I am trying to print (something), if a number in this case 5, is present in this random list in the following way:

```
import random
list = random.sample(range(128), 10)
if list == 5:
    print list
```

Comment: @Kos -- Yeah -- I was debating whether I should fix that syntax error or not ...

Comment: @mgilson I did since no initial whitespace at all was present; go ahead and rollback if you find my edit invalid

Comment: @Kos -- Nah, probably not worth it here.  If it ends up being an issue OP'll let us know.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `in` operator: `if 5 in list`

Also `list` is the name of the type, so I suggest to use another name for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it like this.

```
if 5 in list:
    print list
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried this but I am getting an error that says: SyntaxError:invalid syntax